# What does "well" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is a Merriam Webster definition for "up":

> d: relatively high
> // "the river is up"
> // "was **well** up in her class"

"Well" (source:thefreeditionary.com):

> 15. To a considerable extent or degree: well over the estimate.

Is this the correct definition for this context?

Comment: Which context are you talking about?

Comment: Also, you can use the > symbol to put quoted text (including dictionary definitions) into block quotes. It makes the post much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. "She was in a comparatively high position in her class".

Comment: Wait, I tough "high" in this context means how tall she was, but you said she was in a high position. You also confirmed that I'm right but superseded my definitions with the word comparatively which is different.

Comment: It is extremely rare to use _high_ to talk about how tall a person is (we can use it about buildings, and we use _height_ to refer to a person, but we almost always use _tall_ rather than _high_ to describe the person).

Comment: Well, all right, _relatively_ high. As Colin says, in modern English _high_ never refers to how tall a person is, but to their physical or metaphorical position.